# How to insert data in product table with user id rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

Hello I am absolute newbie in rails. creating some application but stuck on some point.

The problem is I want to insert data in products as per user id but it is saying:

**uninitialized constant ProductController**

Here is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #devise_for :users
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations' }
  resources :dashboard
  root to: "home#index"

  namespace :user do
    resources :users
  end

  resources :product
end
```

here is my product controller i.e, product_controller.rb:

```
class Product::ProductController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      flash[:success] = "Product Added"
      redirect_to product_index_path
    else
      flash[:success] = @product.errors.full_messages.join
      redirect_to :back
    end
    end
  end
```

And here is my new.html.erb code:

```
<h2>Add Product</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :product_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

<%= p.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Product" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

I know this thing is wrong too:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
```

How I can make all the parts to one? my goal is to take use to a new page add product name and redirect to product list page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your controller as `products_controller.rb`

Then change

```
class Product::ProductController < ApplicationController
  -------------
end
```

to

```
class Product::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  -------------
end
```

Even routes needs to be changed.
If you want products controller inside a namespace `product` as you mentioned in your question, then you have to declare routes as shown below.

```
namespace :product do
    resources :products
end
```

Comment: I guess changing this alone wouldn't suffice. He should be changing the routes as well. First of all we should clarify from OP whether he needs the namespace or not? If yes, then the routes should have similar code like users for product as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your controller as `products_controller.rb`

Then change

```
class Product::ProductController < ApplicationController
  -------------
end
```

to

```
class Product::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  -------------
end
```

and the routes file should be changed as this

```
  namespace :product do
    resources :products
  end
```

instead of `resources :product`